# Add space between nodes in XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

`XML` file :

```
     <string-name>
      <surname>Husebo</surname><given-names>BS</given-names>
    </string-name>, <string-name>
                     <surname>Ballard</surname> <given-names>C</given-names></string-name>

XSL : 

    <xsl:template match="surname">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test = "following-sibling::node()[not(./*) and normalize-space(.)='']">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

output :  `Husebo BS, Ballard C`

I want to add a space between `< surname>` and `< given-name>` tag after checking a blank space. ex - For first `< string-name>` there is no space between `< surname>` and `< given-name>` so after checking that after `< /surname>` a blankspace should be added. but in the `2nd` `< /string-name>` tag there a blankspace is already exists so no space will be added there. please help !!!

Comment: @Aankhen , I want to know that how can I check the condition, any white space is already exists or not.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: If you got the proper answer please make it accept or ask the doubt if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code hope it will help you:

```
<xsl:template match="surname[not(following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[. = '&#x0020;']])]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

And if you want to make more specific then check that immediate following-sibling is given-name then use this code:

```
<xsl:template match="surname[not(following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[. = '&#x0020;']]) and following-sibling::node()[1][self::given-names]]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as `given-names` is not optional, you can check if the next text node is the same as the next node:

```
  <xsl:template match="surname">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="following-sibling::node()[1] != following-sibling::text()[1]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: please check the above output and this code doesnot produce that output

Comment: Okay. I thought you were asking specifically about the test. Updated.